# Find all values such that .. from a density plot in Python

Tags: python, plot, kernel-density

I plot(x,y) a chart, for which I want to find two things: 
- all values of x for which y>some specified value,
- all values of y for which y>some specified value.

[image: chart]

How can I do it?

Comment: what have you tried so far? You already have `x` and `y` vectors, why not just filter them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,25,101) #x: 101 values between 0 and 25
y = x**2/20 

x[y>30]  #filter output: [ 24.5 ,  24.75,  25.  ]  
y[y>30]  #filter output: [ 30.0125  ,  30.628125,  31.25    ]
```

This assumes that you have access to the values which generated the plot.